# error while compiling Linux kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, kernel, compiling

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

I followed it to compile Linux kernel 4.9/4.8 in Ubuntu 14.04.1,I successed in virtual machine before and I knew how it worked.But when I changed the platform I met the problem like this.

```
CC [M]  drivers/video/fbdev/vga16fb.o
LD [M]  drivers/video/fbdev/via/viafb.o
LD      drivers/video/fbdev/built-in.o
LD [M]  drivers/usb/wusbcore/wusb-wa.o
LD      drivers/usb/built-in.o
LD      drivers/net/ethernet/built-in.o
LD      drivers/net/built-in.o
LD      drivers/video/built-in.o
LD      drivers/built-in.o
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
```

I tried for many times,such as installing dpkg-dev but it didn't work.
I need some help,thx.

Comment: The errors you show are part of the error summary, and NOT the original error. The original error (that you need to fix) happened earlier in the compilation process. Find it.

Comment: I have fixed it and thx.In addition,I want to know how to delete the question?